# can't get AJAX get call to work even so the code seems correct

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Ok fixed jQuery code with help of others on stack overflow

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $(".note").live('click',function() {
      $("#note_utm_con").show();
      $("#note_utm_nt").html("<img src='http://www.ajaxload.info/images/exemples/4.gif' />");

      $.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url: "view.php",
         data: "ajax=1&nid=' + parent.attr('id').replace('record-','')",
         success: function(html){
            $("#note_utm").html(html);
            $("#note_utm_nt").html("");
         },
         error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $("#note_utm_nt").html("<img src='http://www.ajaxload.info/images/exemples/4.gif' /> Error...");
        }
      });
   });
});
```

The PHP code for view.php

```
include 'object/db.class.php';

if($_GET['ajax'] == '1') {

#make a call to my sql to fetch some sort of ID

         $nid = $_GET['nid'];

         $q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `notice` WHERE nid = '".$nid."'");
         $a = mysql_fetch_array($q);

             $nid = stripslashes($a['nid']);
             $note = stripslashes($a['note']);
             $type = stripslashes($a['type']);
             $private = stripslashes($a['private']);
             $date = stripslashes($a['date']);
             $author = stripslashes($a['author']);

         $note_viewer .= <<<NOTE_VIEWER

         <h2>By: $author</h2> - <h2>$date</h2>
         <br/>
         <p>$note</p>
         <p>Request: $private</p>

NOTE_VIEWER;

             echo $note_viewer;


}
```

The AJAX seems to be working now as it gives me Error...

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Are you seeing errors? Is the AJAX call just not going through? Is the call going through, but nothing is happening after that? Btw, you're missing a closing double-quote for your `data` property.

Comment: No it seems like nothing happens when clicked as if there is not only any request being send truth nothing is displayed as well so #note_utm_con is not even shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

concerning the docu of jQuery, you attach an event with the [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method. In your code, you define the click-method of node twice, I think: once with the live-attaching-stuff and once with note.[click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/). So it is not clear what to do when clicking or better when node is clicked, the click-event is defined :-) You define two different actions when note is clicked... try this one:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $(".note").live('click',function() {
      $("#note_utm_con").show();
      $("#note_utm_nt").html("<img src='http://www.ajaxload.info/images/exemples/4.gif' />");

      $.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url: "view.php",
         data: "ajax=1&nid=' + parent.attr('id').replace('record-',''),
         success: function(html){
            $("#note_utm").html(html);
            $("#note_utm_nt").html("");
         }
      });
   });
});
```

Comment: ok that works but this time it just loops truth the loader and does not load the data, but definitely calls the classes

Comment: Nice... what do you mean by "loops through loader"?

Comment: P.S. added error call back to AJAX so it seems to be calling error instead of the ajax get hmm.

Comment: done re-edited my post with new working AJAX code as well as view.php code

Comment: Thank you! You should output the "errorThrown" parameter:
error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {$("#note_utm_nt").html(errorThrown);} This contains the http information about the error. Just have a look at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ and there error

Comment: a i see, well it returns Not Found even so its in the same folder as notes.php is just that notes is called from _class.php to the main directory via ajax as well

Comment: So you just have to to correct the path of view.php and it should work :-) A good idea is to use absolute paths... for example "/dir/of/view.php"

Comment: fixed path, but it displays everything but not the actual info. So By: is empty - Date: empty and the note it self is empty lol

Comment: So the $_GET['ajax']==1 part is executed, right? So now you have to check where your values are getting lost :-) Are they transferred correctly? Try to set the value of nid manually

Comment: It is not really funny, it just means that your parent.attr('id').replace('record-','') part is crap :-) I would guess that "parent" makes no sense... you should have something like $('parent') (see the jQuery docu how to select elements properly)

Comment: ops not sure how i missed that since I swear I accepted it, having some mouse problem so sorry about that

Comment: Never mind! Accepting didn't work unfortunately :-( For me it is still shown as unaccepted...

Comment: how about now now? i am telling you i got one messed mouse, my mouse went truth allot of bubble games which ended up killing it. Had to change few mouses since my friends keep playing that retarded game. They even killed my Logitech so I have no words, bubbles is a mouse killer sad

Comment: Great, thank you :-) You destroyed a logitech mouse? Ok, hard game with a lot of clicking action ^^

Comment: lol my Dell mouse went out first, then some cheap mouse that I had for over 5 years from Hop Gear worked then it got messed over again, then went out and got Logitech and that broke the fastest which is funny as hell

Answer (score 0):

So what exactly is it doing? and What element is not visible? Your AJAX call isnt even using the response. If I understand your logic correctly, it should be...

```
$.ajax({
                   type: "GET",
                   url: "view.php",
                   data: "ajax=1&nid=' + parent.attr('id').replace('record-',''),
                   success: function(html){
                        $("#note_utm").html(html);
                        $("#note_utm_nt").html(html);
                   }
    });
```

the "html" variable in the success function is the response from the php script.

Comment: it supposed to open something like inline modular window based of request from  <a href="#!/note/$nid" id="record-$nid" onclick="retun false;" class="note"> which is then should be passed to AJAX to get the $nid from the id="record-$nid" and pass it off to AJAX call to view.php so it can load the note into the page